# Some problems with MariaDB syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

> Good evening, here is my code sample. After execution i getting syntax error. Please help me resolve this issue.
>   [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWexf.png)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `catalog_get_options_in_model`(
  IN inModelId INT,
  IN inShortOptionDescriptionLenght INT,
  IN inOptionsPerPage INT,
  IN inStartItem INT
)      

BEGIN

PREPARE
  `stmt` AS

SELECT
  `option`.opion_id,
  `option`.name,

IF(
    LENGHT(`option`.`description`) <= @p1,
    `option`.`description` CONCAT(
      LEFT(`option`.`description`,
      @p2),
      '...'
    )
  ) 

AS `description`,
  `option`.price,
  `option`.`discounted_price`,
  `option`.`thumbnail`


FROM
  `option`.`option_id`


INNER JOIN
  `option_model`.`option_id` ON `option`.`option_id` = `option_model`.`option_id`


WHERE
  `option_model`.`model_id` = @p3


ORDER BY
  `option`.`display` DESC
LIMIT @p4, @p5


SET
  @p1 = inShortOptionDescriptionLength


SET
  @p2 = inShortOptionDescriptionLength


SET
  @p3 = inModelId


SET
  @p4 = inStartItem


SET
  @p5 = inOptionsPerPage


EXECUTE
  `stmt` USING @p1,
  @p2,
  @p3,
  @p4,
  @p5
END $$
```

Comment: `LENGHT` is misspelled

Comment: Oh, i fixed LENGTH but still getting the same error

Comment: COmment 2 then: You do not have any `;` ending your statements.

Comment: `IF(
    LENGHT(`option`.`description`) <= @p1,` but **@p1** is not defined yet. Same for all other vars you are trying to use in query. My guess you should use **?** as placeholder. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, using `?` as placeholder helps me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF( LENGHT(option.description) <= @p1`

but @p1 is not defined yet.

Same for all other vars you are trying to use in query.

My guess you should use **?** as placeholder.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: **IF** I recall correctly, prepared statements can't use `?` in `LIMIT` clauses. ...Nevermind, I must be thinking of something else, or a much older version of MySQL.

Comment: you can just SET vars before you generate query string

Answer (score 0):

Spelling:  LENGHT -- as already noted, there are other error.